# windows batch if statement only works if all on one line

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

The context of this problem was ImageMagick, but the problem is a general one.

I was trying to write a batch file shell to conditionally call one of two ImageMagick exe files depending on which was installed (the same batch file can run on 2 different PC's).

I have the shell batch file `IM.BAT`:

```
if exist "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\"  "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\Convert" %*
if exist "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q8\"   "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q8\Convert" %*
```

and call it from this file `MergeImages.BAT`:

```
:    Use:  call MergeImages <input file1> <input file2> <output file>   
:
    call IM.bat ^
     "%~1" ^
     ^( "%~2" -gravity center  ^) ^
     -composite ^
     "png32:%~3"
```

and call that in turn from `TEST.BAT`:

```
call MergeImages.bat image1.png image2.png image3.png
```

it all works as expected.  However when I tried to clean up the flow of `IM.BAT`:

```
if exist "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\" (
  "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\Convert" %*
  goto :EOF
  )
if exist "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q8\" (
  "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q8\Convert" %*
  goto :EOF
  )
echo Error: No executable found
```

I get the error `-composite was unexpected at this time`.  I'm sure the error is coming from the batch processor rather than ImageMagick and is probably due to the use of parentheses on the previous line, but I have no idea how to get it working.  Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `)` in `^( "%~2" -gravity center  ^) ^` is prematurely closing the IF block in IM.BAT. The escape you currently have isn't doing anything, since it is removed before IM.BAT can see it. Also, the escape of the opening `(` is not needed.

There are a few options to fix your problem.

option 1: modify MergeImages.bat

```
:    Use:  call MergeImages <input file1> <input file2> <output file>   
:
    call IM.bat ^
     "%~1" ^
     ( "%~2" -gravity center  ^^) ^
     -composite ^
     "png32:%~3"
```

option 2: modify IM.BAT

```
if exist "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\" ^
  "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q16\Convert" %* & goto :EOF
if exist "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q8\" ^
  "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.8-Q8\Convert" %* & goto :EOF
echo Error: No executable found
```

---

I'm not sure, but are those parentheses even needed? I've never seen parentheses used like that in an argument list (and I haven't used ImageMagick). I'm wondering if MergeImages.bat could be as simple as:

```
:    Use:  call MergeImages <input file1> <input file2> <output file>   
:
    call IM.bat ^
     "%~1" ^
     "%~2" -gravity center ^
     -composite ^
     "png32:%~3"
```

Comment: Perfect.  Option 1 fixed the problem, but yes, in this context the parentheses are not required but its nice to know how to deal with them inside conditionals (in ImageMagick parentheses are used place image results on a stack).  Many thanks for your comprehensive answer.